# VirtualAllocEx failing with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED code

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, access-denied, interprocess

My program (LibInjector) tries to allocate memory in another process (Recipient) and fails, GetLastError() returns 5(ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED).
Usually it works (for recipients such as my other program or notepad.exe), and I don't know why VirtualAllocEx doesn't work in this particular case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: LibInjector [receiver process ID] [dll name]!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int iProcessId = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (!iProcessId)
    {
        printf("Failed to parse process ID! Current process ID will be used.\n");
        iProcessId = GetCurrentProcessId();
    }
    const char* psDllName = argv[2];
    printf("Receiver process id: %d\n", iProcessId);
    //PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION
    HANDLE hTargetProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, iProcessId);
    if (hTargetProcess == NULL)
    {
        printf("OpenProcess failed with code %d !\n", GetLastError());
        return 2;
    }
    SIZE_T stDllNameLen = strlen(psDllName);
    LPVOID lpDllNameAddress = VirtualAllocEx(hTargetProcess, NULL, stDllNameLen + 1, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (lpDllNameAddress == NULL)
    {
        printf("VirtualAllocEx failed with code %d !\n", GetLastError());
        return 3;
    }
        //unreachable
}
```

- The platforms of both processes (LibInjector and Recipient) are 32 bit;
- Both processes running by the same user;
- Both processes has elevated privileges;
- Process explorer (running elevated) shows an empty Protection field for recipient;
- Recipient's exe file had digital signature, I set VirtualAddress and Size of Security Directory in Optional PE Header to 0. Now there is no Digital Signature tab in Recipient's exe file properties, but VirtualAllocEx still throws the same ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

**UPD:**

- RtlGetLastNtStatus also returns 0xC0000022, which means `{Access Denied} A process has requested access to an object but has not been granted those access rights.`
- calling `GetSecurityInfo(hTargetProcess, SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, &dacl, &sacl, &pSecDesc);` returns 5

Comment: "My program (LibInjector) tries to allocate memory in another process (Recipient) and fails" - Sounds like a *good* thing to me..

Comment: I solemnly swear that my intentions are innocent :)

Comment: Good intentions don't mean a thing when confronted with [securable objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/securable-objects).

Comment: i doubt that VirtualAllocEx return this error, however GetLastError() not informative here. call `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` in it place and post status

Comment: Does the "bitness" match between the injector and the injectee?

Comment: @RbMm From what I found, the RtlGetLastNtStatus function is not accessible from user mode, how can I call it?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError yes, both are 32-bit

Comment: @BorshKorolevsky *not accessible from user mode* - absolute nonsense, *how can I call it?* - but how you can call `GetLastError` ?! exactly some way and call `RtlGetLastNtStatus` and again i doubt that the `VirtualAllocEx` return this error if you open process with `PROCESS_VM_OPERATION` (and some driver not silent filter this)

Comment: @RbMm I can call GetLastError() because I know, that it declared in errhandlingapi.h and defined in Kernel32 lib, but i can't find anything similar about RtlGetLastNtStatus. Could you help me with that too please? You right about VirtualAllocEx, it returns 0 and then GetLastError() returns 5, which microsoft describes as ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

Comment: @BorshKorolevsky link with `ntdll.lib` or `ntdllp.lib`. declare `RtlGetLastNtStatus` byself. or use debugger, for view returned status directly. and again - `VirtualAllocEx` must not return this error in case you post actual code

Comment: @RbMm Thank you! RtlGetLastNtStatus returns 0xC0000022. {Access Denied} `A process has requested access to an object but has not been granted those access rights.` . But I still have no idea what is causing this.
The code I provided is correct.

Comment: in this case need look under debugger on target system. `VirtualAllocEx` return `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` only in case `hTargetProcess` have no `PROCESS_VM_OPERATION` access rights. i be look on handle actual access

Comment: You really should not be using `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` at all, ever. Only request the specific rights you actually need, which in this case is only `PROCESS_VM_OPERATION`

Comment: I just tested it and successfully used `VirtualAllocEx` to allocate memory to another process. So the process Recipient must be very special. May I ask how you create it?

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT Recipient is unofficial mmo game client

Comment: Look to handle actual access. Maybe in system exist driver, which protect this game and silent cut access when process open. In any case problem not in your code ( if it relevant) need look with debugger and tools on target system for exactly research what is happens

Comment: @RbMm Thanks, I'll try and post the results in this topic. I'll have to figure out how to do this because I've never done this before

Comment: No, call GetSecurityInfo is senseless. You need call NtQueryObject on process handle for check GrantedAccess. Or use some tools, like process hacker for look handle access

Comment: @BorshKorolevsky "*Recipient is unofficial mmo game client*" - a lot of games take extra measures to prevent users from messing around with their memory, ie anti-cheating, etc. This might be a case of that. Can you reproduce the same problem in a [mcve] using 2 simple apps that you create yourself?

Comment: @RemyLebeau OP already did that: "Usually it works (for recipients such as my other program or notepad.exe)." I also suspect that the target program has anti-cheat measures in place.